# Sorting Combobox with BindingSource.Sort, whats wrong here:

Tags: c#, sorting, combobox, bindingsource

Cant get the code below to sort the Combobox (drpBox2) correctly.

```
BindingSource bsAddresses = new BindingSource();
bsAddresses.DataSource = searchedAddr;
bsAddresses.Sort = "timesUsed ASC";
drpBox2.DataSource = bsAddresses.DataSource;
drpBox2.DisplayMember = "address";
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Provide XAML and sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple error in the code, when using a BindingSource you must bind your Controls to the BS directly, not to its DataSource. In your Code, both `bsAddresses` and `drpBox2` are bound to `searchedAddr` so the sorted BindingSource is not used at all. Fixed code:

```
BindingSource bsAddresses = new BindingSource();
bsAddresses.DataSource = searchedAddr;
bsAddresses.Sort = "timesUsed ASC";
drpBox2.DataSource = bsAddresses;
drpBox2.DisplayMember = "address";
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be two issues here

- The Column required is case sensitive, so you should be supplying it
  in the proper case(ascending is default)
- Also for the underlying List to get sorted it must implement
  `IBindingList` (If not then `SupportsSorting` property would be false, indicating that source doesn't support sorting)

[Read Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.sort.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I noticed it was just as easy to sort the list before binding it, so thats what I did. Thanks though.